# loading a div with jquery load() and changing the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I've got a load function like this:

```
function loadComprar(){
  $("#Inicio").fadeOut(300, function(){
    $("#Inicio").load("x.html", function(){
      $(this).fadeIn(300);
    });
  });
};
```

But it's missing something to change the URL when the load is executed.
I tried using the `history.pushState()` function but I'm not sure if I missed something or what, but if I reload the page, it says the url is invalid (which is right, because I don't have a file in the url I'm changing). Any tips?

Comment: Are you looking for the ability to go back in the browsers history to go back through the states of the particular div? if so, you would want to look at http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Comment: I think that's what I want, I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "Back Button & Query", you need to look at a plugin that is already designed to help you with this such as [Back Button & Query](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

I found out a nice way of doing what I wanted, if anyone was wondering, check this site:
[simple-ajax-website-jquery](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/)